# Error 500 Internal Server Error en Script de laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

Hola gente estoy intentando tener una lista de test a mi vista en la cual tenga un buscador que "filtre" por el nombre.
Con las actuales configuraciones solo me salta el error

> 500 internal server error.

Mi controlador

```
public function searchTest(Request $request)
{
     try {
            $name = $request->input('name');
            $userId = Auth::id();

            // Realiza la búsqueda en la base de datos con la relación
            $tests = Test::join('users', 'test.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                         ->where('users.id', $userId)
                         ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')
                         ->select('test.id as test_id', 'users.name as user_name','test.*')
                         ->get();

            // Muestra los resultados para fines de depuración
            

            // Devuelve los resultados en formato JSON
            return response()->json($tests);
        } else {
            // El usuario no cumple con las condiciones, realiza la acción apropiada
            return response()->json(['error' => 'No autorizado'], 401);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Registra la excepción para su análisis
        Log::error($e);
        dd($e);
        // Devuelve una respuesta de error al cliente
        
    }
}
```

[image: Script de mi view]

Ahi les dejo el script que encontre por internet pero de seguro que no pude adecuarlo a mi proyecto.Entiendo que el error esta en el buscar-test.Espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: as intentado revisar el log? `storage\log\laravel.log` a ver que te indica o porque se da el error?

Comment: Bro como estas? cuando abro el log me salta miles de errores de hace muchisimo.Hay alguna forma de filtrar?

Comment: Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'test.user_id' in 'on clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `test`.`id` as `test_id`, `users`.`name` as `user_name`, `test`.* from `test` inner join `users` on `test`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`id` = 1 and `users`.`name` LIKE %ada%) ese es el error que me da cuando realizo la "consulta"

Comment: 1. El código siempre _como texto con formato_. 2. Lo que escribiste como comentario es información relevante en tu pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para agregarla. 3. ¿Existe _'test.user_id'_? Hay que leer los errores...

Comment: el error el claro no existe la columna `test.user_id` ....

Comment: Ya solucione ese problema de momento no tira ningun error en la vista ni en la consola, en la consola me da una lista de listas en la cual cuando quiero ver sus atributos aparece el error: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:3:28)]